# R httpd issue - help pages fail to load using local IP

Tags: r, apache

This may be a general topic, but I came across the issue while working on some code using the Rook package.

The recent R versions include an http server. You may have seen this while checking for help topics using RGui. It opens a new browser with the IP/Port, etc.

For eg., if I enter ?paste, this brings up,

http://127.0.0.1:31234/library/.../paste.html

But if I use my IP, say 192.168.1.2 in place of 127.0.0.1, the page fails to load, I get an error

```
    While trying to retrieve the URL:http://192....
    The following error was encountered:
    We can not connect to the server you have requested
```

I have other apps that have httpd interfaces, and I can go to those app's http interfaces using both 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.2 ... etc. So, as far as system/network permissions are concerned - I do not think that is the issue here.

Rather, there is something specific to the R httpd process that disallows it to be accessed using the domain name, etc ?

The above was tested in a corporate network. When I tried the same process from my home network it worked fine. However, since I already access http interfaces of many other locally installed apps from the corporate PC, I think there might be something specific to R's http process that needs to be checked ?

Workstation is running - Windows XP

Please let me know if you have any thoughts on the above,

Regards,

- Raj.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. The trick is to specify,

```
s <- Rhttpd$new()
s$start(listen="0.0.0.0",port="20000")
```

when starting the Rook process. Specifying 0.0.0.0 makes it listen to all the interfaces and now I can access it using my external IP. Thanks a lot for your help nonetheless !

Answer (score 0):

When opening a TCP port, the local IP address may be chosen.  For incoming connections, typically INADDR_ANY (-1) is supplied to bind(), which means to open the port on every available interface.

However, it is quite possible to open a port on just one interface on your machine (in this case, 127.0.0.1), simply by supplying the IP address of the interface.  Seems that R does just this.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you may have a proxy in place on your corporate network. Your browser is probably configured to use that proxy to access the Internet. Most browsers will exclude an address which they know to be local (`127.0.0.1` or `localhost`) from using the proxy, but might not exclude any other IP.

Try disabling the proxy in your browser (even "Auto-Detect", completely turn the proxy off) and see if you're able to connect.

Comment: I checked a bit more ... since I can access http interfaces on other apps and I am trying to access the R httpd internally also, not from outside.    P:\>netstat -an | find "14539"
    TCP    **127.0.0.1**:14539        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

(Port 14539 is where I have R httpd running)

whereas the other apps that have http interfaces -

    P:\>netstat -an | find "1234"
    TCP    **0.0.0.0**:1234           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING


So, the R httpd is only listening on 127.0.0.1 and not on 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces). Any idea on how this can be corrected ?

Thanks,

- Raj.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

If you are using RStudio, this might be a bug in the RStudio. Check out this link:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202656007-Cryptic-error-on-starting-RStudio-daily-with-R-devel

Updating to the latest version of RStudio with the latest version of R fixes the problem.